# Setting the font for the languages other than english

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am doing a Font application for the Mac. I got all the font names from the location `"/Library/Fonts/"` and saved them in an array named `FontArray`. I just have to preview all the fonts in a NSTextView. This is my code for the NSTextView:

```
NSTextView *textView=[[NSTextView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(250,500,450,30)];
[textView setString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMMOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];
[textView setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:[FontArray objectAtindex:rowid] size:40]];
```

This function will be called when a tableview row has been clicked. This works correctly for all the english fonts. But whenever non english fonts clicked means it gives an error like            `*** -[NSTextView setFont:]: nil NSFont given.` How can I change my code to correct this error.

Comment: anyone please give the suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on a completely wrong road. A font is not a font file; the name of the font contained inside a font file is not necessarily the same as the name of the file, as you've discovered. Instead of trying to work with the font files directly, use `NSFontManager`.

Comment: May I know how to get the Font name from the font file?